# C++ bool std::operator < error with map with key std::unordered_set<int,std::hash<int>>

Tags: c++, unordered-set

when I try to insert in this map:

`std::map<std::unordered_set<int >, std::pair<float, std::pair<float, float >> >`

**I got this error**

> error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const
>   std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for
>   'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const
>   std::unordered_set,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>'

**My data is defined as follows:**

```
    struct Trans {
    int Item;
    float Prob;
    float W;
};
bool operator<(const Trans &a, const Trans &b)
    {
        return a.Item < b.Item;
    }
    bool operator==( Trans c,  Trans d) { return c.Item == d.Item; }


    struct MyHash {
        size_t operator()(const Trans& x) const { return std::hash<int>()(x.Item);  }
    };


std::vector<std::vector<Trans>> data;
std::map<std::unordered_set<int>, float> S1;
std::map<std::unordered_set<int >, std::pair<float, std::pair<float, float >> > S2;
std::map<std::unordered_set<int >, std::pair<float, std::pair<float, float >> > S3;
```

**The part that has the problem:**

```
    do
        {

std::unordered_set<Trans, MyHash> KS(data[i].begin(), data[i].begin() + k);
std::unordered_set<int > elem;

float esupp = 1;
float Weight = 0;
float Wesupp = 1;
    for (auto const &iter : KS)
        {
          elem.insert(iter.Item);
           esupp *= iter.Prob;
          Weight += iter.W;
        }
        Weight = Weight / k;


        /*
        some code, and until here I didn't get any problem
        */

            **// This the area that has the problem** 

    S1[elem] = std::move(S1[elem] + esupp);
    Wesupp = Weight * S1[elem];
    S2[elem].first = std::move(S2[elem].first + esupp);
    S2[elem].second = std::make_pair(elem, Wesupp);
  } while (next_combination(data[i].begin(), data[i].begin() + k, data[i].end()));
```

Comment: What is the actual line that has the error?

Comment: Beyond the rest, this line doesn't look right: `S2[elem].second = std::make_pair(elem, Wesupp);`

Comment: I would seriously reconsider the data structure design... `unordered_set` as keys? `std::pair<float, std::pair<float, float>>`? (at least use a `std::tuple` or `std::array<float, 3>`)

Comment: @ben every line from ` S1[elem] = std::move(S1[elem] + esupp)` to ` S2[elem].second = std::make_pair(elem, Wesupp);` cause the error

Comment: @marco-a in the container `S2` I would like to insert the `unordered_set` `elem` with its three float values. every round in the loop `elem` has `unordered_set`, if its similar to the previous one, I will update their three float values, otherwise I will insert new `unordered_set` with its three float values.

Comment: @t-c it's good suggestion but still I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

A [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) expects its key to implement the operator `<`, unless a comparator is supplied.

Your key type, [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) doesn't implement "less than".

As @T.C. mentions, you could use `std::set` instead of `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: thanks, but If I replace the `std::map` with `std::unordered_map` I will get another error, `error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.`

Comment: @Sandy I'll remove that suggestion then.  The cause for your error remains the same.  C++ does not support that.

Comment: `std::set` does have `operator <()` defined by the standard.

Comment: Thank you all, I need to use `std::unordered_set` not `std::set` because, I used hash function for checking if `KS` if super set of any of the previous set that stored in `S2', I have file of 100k lines, each line has different size, and I used `next_combination` for generating `KS`, and I used hashing for the comparisons part to reduce the time instead of using the `STL includes() `

Comment: @Sandy Did you actually measure the speed with `std::set` / `std::includes`? When talking about performance, *always* measure.

Comment: @t-c yes, I did, and I test also by using profiler. in large data file, using has function is better than using `std::includes`. my problem is how to define `S2` to carry the results.

Answer (score 1):

Your current error, as Drew Dormann pointed out, is caused by `std::unordered_set`'s lack of an `operator <`.

`std::set`, however, does have an overloaded `operator <`, so you can use that.

The problem with your code runs deeper than that, though. For instance:

```
S1[elem] = std::move(S1[elem] + esupp);
```

You are assigning a `float`. There's absolutely no point in using `std::move`, especially as `S1[elem] + esupp` is already an rvalue. The usual way of writing this line would be `S1[elem] += esupp;`

```
S2[elem].first = std::move(S2[elem].first + esupp);
```

Same problem.

```
S2[elem].second = std::make_pair(elem, Wesupp);
```

The LHS of the assignment is a `std::pair<float, float>`; the RHS creates a `std::pair<std::unordered_set<int>, float>`.

And as I mentioned in the comments, `std::pair<float, std::pair<float, float>>` is just bad design. It should be at least `std::tuple` or even better a `std::array<float, 3>` or even better a simple struct that makes clear what each of the three floats actually mean.

Further, using a `set<int>` (unordered or not) as a key in a map is a fairly weird design. Do you want to just maintain a list of `set<int>`-3x`float` pairings that you can iterate through, or do you actually want to be able to efficiently index with a `set<int>`? If you don't need the efficient indexing, just use a vector of pairs rather than a map.

Comment: English is not my first language, so I used example to describe S2, I wish you have time to look at it. http://im67.gulfup.com/REB8Fj.png